# How to correctly form a POST request to this website with python request

Tags: python, post, web-scraping

The url I'd like to send post request to is http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx

The search I'd like to do (manually) is simply input "1" in "Stock Code" and click "Search"

I have tried many time with python and chrome extension "Postman" sending post request with the following header:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1844
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: TS0161f2e5=017038eb490da17e158ec558c902f520903c36fad91e96a3b9ca79b098f2d191e3cac56652
Host: www.hkexnews.hk
Origin: http://www.hkexnews.hk
Referer: http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36
```

and the following as params:

```
today: 20180624
sortBy: 
selPartID: 
alertMsg: 
ddlShareholdingDay: 23
ddlShareholdingMonth: 06
ddlShareholdingYear: 2018
txtStockCode: 00001
txtStockName: 
txtParticipantID: 
txtParticipantName: 
btnSearch.x: 35
btnSearch.y: 8
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below way. It should fetch you the required response along with the tabular data available in that site generated according to the search criteria.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select("input[name]")}
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'btnSearch'
    payload['txtStockCode'] = '00001'
    payload['txtParticipantID'] = 'A00001'
    req = s.post(URL,data=payload,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup_obj.select("#pnlResultSummary .ccass-search-datarow"):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("div")]
        print(data)
```

Comment: If it is, make sure to tick the grayed out checkmark next to my answer to accept it as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM: Some params in payload have been updated, also the `table` has been replaced with `div`, I tried modifying your code but it doesn't seem to work. However, it works fine from POSTMAN. Here's my code:https://pastebin.com/Sd0pkCm7. Could you help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: Check out the update @Chankey Pathak. This time the above implementation is more robust I believe. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM Thank you so much! I needed the data from 2nd table, so I used below `for items in soup_obj.select("table tbody tr"): data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")]`

Comment: @SIM: I noticed that it always returns the data for the current date. I'm trying to get the data for a specific date by passing `payload['txtShareholdingDate']: data_date` but it still returns the data for the current date. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sure. Add this line `payload['txtShareholdingDate'] = '2018/05/01'`. The rest are as it is. This is just a date `2018/05/01` to show you that it works otherwise. . Did you use the same format of date. I just checked and found it working.

Answer (score 0):

If the news site provides a search API and you have the access then you can use something like Postman to get the search results. Otherwise, you will have scrape the results.

The use case you mentioned is typical of scraping. See if there is a search API, if not use something like `selenium` to scrape the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am just exploring if there are any light-weight solutions that don't require the overhead of running a browser.

Comment: Browser emulation might not be as "heavy" as you think. You don't necessarily have to emulate the big ones(Chrome/Firefox) if what you want to do is just click a button. There are many ghost browser implementations that are lightweight. Take a look here https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers